# Unable To Submit iOS 9 Apps (Invalid Swift Support)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, swift2, xcode7

We were able to submit builds to iTunes Connect for internal beta testing just fine with Xcode 6.X. Now that we have upgraded our Swift project to Xcode 7 and Swift 2, we have been getting the "Invalid Swift Support" error:

```
Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, libswiftCoreData.dylib, libswiftAVFoundation.dylib 
don’t match /Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, 
/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, 
/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib, 
/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib. Make sure the
files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it. Don’t apply 
post processing to /Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,     
/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib, 
/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
```

Comment: What version of Xcode 7 are you using?

Comment: Xcode 7 Golden Master

Comment: Submitting iOS 9 apps is not available yet. Check https://developer.apple.com/news/ for the announcement.

Comment: There is an issue on github to your problem, maybe this helps you
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4178

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7 is currently in Beta, and Apple do not allow apps built with beta tools to be submitted.

Expect an announcement in the next few days as to when you can submit iOS 9 versions of your app to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a post on twitter going around, but i cant find the original post:

> Apple confirmed TestFlight external test doesn't support iOS 9 GM and
>   it seems they think it is OK and won't fix it.

https://twitter.com/an0/status/642015637678723072